# Jenkins/Hudson - accessing the current build number?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I have a report file I'm generating, and I would like to be able to add the current build number to that file within a Jenkins job. Is there an environment variable or plugin I can use to get at the current build number?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`BUILD_NUMBER` is the current build number. You can use it in the command you execute for the job, or just use it in the script your job executes.

See the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) for the full list of available environment variables. The list is also available from within your Jenkins instance at http://hostname/jenkins/env-vars.html.

Comment: Richard Fearn can you please help me to be more specific abt your ans. i need to get buildnumber of my jenkins job . i'm using Java + maven+ jenkins

Answer (score 20):

Jenkins Pipeline also provides the current build number as the property `number` of the `currentBuild`.  It can be read as `currentBuild.number`.

For example:

```
// Scripted pipeline
def buildNumber = currentBuild.number
```

```
// Declarative pipeline
echo "Build number is ${currentBuild.number}"
```

Other properties of `currentBuild` are described in the Pipeline Syntax: Global Variables page that is included on each Pipeline job page.  That page describes the global variables available in the Jenkins instance based on the current plugins.

Comment: thank you for short and to the point answer

Answer (score 12):

I've just come across this question too and found out that if anytime the build number gets corrupt because of any error-triggered hard shutdown of the jenkins instance you can set back the build number manually by just editing the file **nextBuildNumber** (pathToJenkins\jobs\jobxyz\nextBuildNumber) and then make a reload by using the option
**Reload Configuration from Disk** from the *Manage Jenkins* View.

Answer (score 5):

As per Jenkins Documentation,

> BUILD_NUMBER

is used. This number is identify how many times jenkins run this build process
`$BUILD_NUMBER` is general syntax for it.